# How can I pull 2 paired elements from a csv file and add them to an array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have several csv files that contain order information for products. My csv files look something like below:

```
order_number,sku,qty,price_per,total_price
12345,55555,25,4,100
12346,33333,10,5,50
12347,55555,20,4,80
```

I'm not having any trouble finding out the `total_price` for all transactions, but how can I find the totals on each product? I tried creating an array for each, but I can't figure out how to keep the `sku` and `total_price` elements bound together.

**Update #2**

Since I can't have an array with matching keys, and since I want to end up here anyway, how can I get an array like this:

```
Array(
      [55555] => 180
      [33333] => 50
     )
```

If anyone has any ideas on how I can make this array that would be great. Thanks!

**Update #1**

Sorry, I spaced adding my code, here it is:

```
foreach($files as $file){
  $fh = fopen($file, 'rb');
  while($col = fgetcsv($fh)) {
  $csv[] = $col;
  $total = array($col[27])
  }}
```

Comment: It's not possible to have this as an array the way you're asking. Arrays cannot have duplicate keys with different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want, i.e. create an array $totals which sums the totals over skus:

```
   $totals = array();
   foreach($files as $file) {
        $fh = fopen($file, 'rb');
        while($col = fgetcsv($fh)) {
          $csv[] = $col;
          $total = array($col[27])
          $totals[$col[1]] += $col[27];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I need. I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Current answers don't produce the array you're after:

```
Array(
      [55555] => 100
      [33333] => 50
      [55555] => 80
     )
```

Because this can't be done - 55555 can't be used as a key twice. An alternative would be to have an array of the form:

```
Array(
          [12345] => array("sku"=>55555,"total_price"=>100),
          [12346] => array("sku"=>33333,"total_price"=>50),
          [12347] => array("sku"=>55555,"total_price"=>80),
         )
```

This code produces the second array:

```
$trans = array();
foreach($files as $file){
    $fh = fopen($file, 'rb');
    while($col = fgetcsv($fh)) {
        $trans[$col[0]] = array("sku"=>$col[0],"total_price"=>$col[27]);
    }
}
```

Assuming `$col[0]` is order and `$col[1]` is sku.